# EF Select Grandparent for Grandchildren

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Class Brands, Models, Generations, Modification

How to get all Brands for ModificationName == "ACK"

```
public class Brand
    {
        public Brand()
        {
            this.Models = new HashSet<Model>();
        }
        public int BrandId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Model> Models { get; set; }
    }

public class Model
    {
        public Model()
        {
            this.Generations = new HashSet<Generation>();
        }
        
        public virtual ICollection<Generation> Generations { get; set; }
        public int? BrandId { get; set; }
        public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
    }

public class Generation
{
    public Generation()
        {
            this.Modifications = new HashSet<Modification>();
        }
        public int GenerationId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Modification> Modifications { get; set; }
        public int? ModelId { get; set; }
        public virtual Model Model { get; set; }
}

public class Modification
{
        public int ModificationId { get; set; }
        public string ModificationName { get; set; }

        public int? GenerationId { get; set; }
        public virtual Generation Generation { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trick here is to use `SelectMany` method.

```cs
var query = 
   from b in ctx.Brands
   where b.Models
     .SelectMany(m => m.Generations.SelectMany(g => g.Modifications))
     .Where(m => m.ModificationName == "ACK").Any()
   select b;
```

**UPDATE with includes**

It will work only with EF Core 5

```cs
var query = 
   from b in ctx.Brands
     .Include(b => b.Models)             
     .ThenInclude(g => g.Generations)             
     .ThenInclude(m => m.Modifications.Where(x => x.ModificationName == "ACK"))
   where b.Models
     .SelectMany(m => m.Generations.SelectMany(g => g.Modifications))
     .Where(m => m.ModificationName == "ACK").Any()
   select b;
```

Comment: thanks. And how to select Brands with Models, Generations only if ModificationName == "ACK" ?

Comment: Add `from b in ctx.Brands.Include(b => b.Models)` rest not changed

Comment: When I add `ctx.Brands.Include(b => b.Models).ThenInclude(g=>g.Generations).ThenInclude(m=>m.Modification`) rest not changed. I get all Brands with all Models and all Generations and Modification for this Brands when modicicationName =="ACK" . I want to get all Brands only with Models, only witch Generations and Modifications where modificationName == "ACK". I don't want to in query result modifications where modificationName != "ACK". But thank you very much for your help !

Comment: So where is filter that I have introduced?

Comment: `var query = _repo.Brands.Include(b => b.Models)
            .ThenInclude(g => g.Generations)
            .ThenInclude(m => m.Modifications)
            .Where(b => b.Models.SelectMany(m => m.Generations
           .SelectMany(g => g.Modifications))
                   .Where(m => m.ModificationName.Trim().ToUpper()
                   .Contains(modificationContains.Trim().ToUpper())).Any());`

Comment: Updated answer with filtered Include.

Comment: I give up ! Sorry

Comment: @RafałBędkowski, I'm confused. It is acceptable answer or not? If yes, mark that answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to use the Join operator. For example>

from currentBrand in Context.Brand
join currentModel in context.Model on currentBrand.Id equals currentModel.BrandId
join currentGeneration in context.Generations on currentGeneration.ModelId  equals currentModel.id
join currentModeification in context.Modification on  currentModeification.GenerationId  equals currentGeneration .Id
Where  currentModeification.ModificationName == "ACK"

Comment: This is also wrong answer. After these joins you will have brand multiplication.